# Cumulative inflation calculation

Tags: r, loops

I have a vector containing inflation estimates for the next 10 years as so:

```
inflation <- c(2.7/100,2.6/100,2.2/100,1.9/100,1.9/10,rep(2/100,5))
```

I want the total multiplier for inflation in N years. So the first year is `i_0=1+2.7/100`, then successive years are the previous year times 1 + the inflation for that year. I can do this with a loop, but I'm trying to do things the R way.

So what I have is:

```
cumulative_inflation<- rep(1,10)
cumulative_inflation[1]<-1.027
for(i in 2:10){
cumulative_inflation[i]=(1+inflation[i])*cumulative_inflation[i-1]}
```

I'd use Purr, but I'm stuck on R2.14, which has /very/ little of the tidyverse available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too hard to accomplish in base R:

```
cumprod(1 + inflation)
 [1] 1.027000 1.053702 1.076883 1.097344 1.305840 1.331956
 [7] 1.358596 1.385767 1.413483 1.441752
```

`cumprod`, as you might guess from the name, is the cumulative product.

Test for equality.

```
all.equal(cumprod(1+inflation), cumulative_inflation)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce('*', inflation + 1, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 1.027000 1.053702 1.076883 1.097344 1.305840 1.331956 1.358596 
#    1.385767 1.413483 1.441752
```